# Elementary app feasibility: modify any current text input

Tags: gtk, vala

I'm using a qwerty keyboard with english layout but as a french speaker I would like to access special chars without changing the layout.

To do so, I'd like to create an app that mimic the android behavior of longpress on a key:

- Long pressing any alphabeticall key would launch a popup which would grab input focus
- It would show the list of variations of the letter you long pressed and you could select the one you want with the arrow key (or maybe by pressing the key again)
- Pressing enter would then give the focus back to the input text, send a 'Suppr' keyboard command to erase the original key pressed and paste the selected variation

I started to read the Developper guide for elementary but as I never worked with Valaa nor Gtk+ I'm not sure it's the way to go.

Is this doable in Vala/Gtk?

Answer (score 2):

All feature requests must be written to the proper GitHub page, they do not belong here.

I believe that in your case [gala](/questions/tagged/gala) is a good starting point.

https://github.com/elementary/gala

Good luck

Comment: It's not really a feature request as I am willing to do it myself, it was just a technical question. I'll check gala out :)